# what is the differences between Membership, SimpleMembership, ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

what is the differences between `Membership`, `SimpleMembership`, `ASP.NET Identity`?

- Which one is best in web forms?
- How to use `SimpleMembership` in web forms.
- Limitation with `SimpleMembership` in web forms.

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/all-this-microsoft-membership-identity-stuff-whats-it-about-4db18dccd9d8

Answer (score 7):

You listed them in progressive order by age. The Asp.net Membership Provider was first introduced with .net 2.0. Later. Simple Membership was released but most recently Microsoft has replaced SimpleMembership with Asp.net Identity (Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.Core). This article should help you understand... [Forms authentication using ASP.NET Identity & VS 2013](http://www.novanet.no/blog/olav-nybo/dates/2013/8/forms-authentication-using-aspnet-identity--vs-2013-preview/)

Remember, there are changes currently taking place between the RC version of AspNet Identity and the RTM version which has not yet been released.

Here's another article that will help you. [Introducing ASP.NET Identity – A membership system for ASP.NET applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx)

Comment: Updated link: http://blog.novanet.no/forms-authentication-using-asp-net-identity-vs-2013-preview/

Comment: Seems like the re-updated link should now be: http://blog.novanet.no/forms-authentication-using-asp-net-identity/