# asp Membership updating wrong tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I have an MVC 4 app that I am trying to use Membership to manage Roles and Authentication.  The problem I am seeing is that when I open the ASP Configuration app, I add users and I see them show up in the aspnet_users table.  But when I go to the mvc app and register a user, it gets saved in the userprofile table.

There is obviously a lot that I don't understand here.  When I go to my project in Visual Studio 2012 Express and select the Project Menu and then Configure asp.net, where is the configuration for that app?  It seems as though I need to look at the configuration and make sure the connection string is working and that I have the correct provider specified.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "ASP Configuration App" (although I'm not sure of what it is) must be using the old `ASP.NET Membership` whereas your ASP .NET MVC 4 application is using `SimpleMembership`. MVC 5 uses `ASP.NET Identity`.

Chronollogically: `ASP.NET Membership` > `SimpleMembership` > [`ASP.NET Identity`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx).

See this question: [what is the differences between Membership, SimpleMembership, ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088007/what-is-the-differences-between-membership-simplemembership-asp-net-identity)

[This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) may also be useful.